# Camera preview more smooth change orientation Ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, animation, camera

I am using `AVFoundation` to add camera preview. I have a problem with smooth orientation change (Portrait to Landscape), there is a **jump** when changing rotation **(~30deg)**.

[image]

I want to do this more smoothly.

```
viewWillTransitionMethod:
    [coordinator animateAlongsideTransition:^(id<UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext>  _Nonnull context) {

        UIInterfaceOrientation targetOrientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];

        if ([self.session isRunning]) {
            [CATransaction begin];
            [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:[context transitionDuration]];
            [CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];

            if (targetOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
                self.previewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            } else if (targetOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
                self.previewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(-M_PI_2, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            } else {
                self.previewLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
            }

            [self.previewLayer setFrame:self.cameraPreview.frame];
            [CATransaction commit];
        }
```

Comment: But why do you want to add animation, it is default your camera automatically rotates to whatever rotation your device is in.

Comment: cuz its happen too slowly, its a bad looking "jump"

Comment: i have diffrent look in portrain and landscape, when rotates its the jump at Ipad (iphone have only portrtain mode).